# Get a similarity matrix from word2vec in python (Gensim)

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I am using the following python code to generate similarity matrix of word vectors (My vocabulary size is `77`).

```
similarity_matrix = []
index = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(model.wv.syn0))

for sims in index:
    similarity_matrix.append(sims)
similarity_array = np.array(similarity_matrix)
```

The dimensionality of the `similarity_array` is `300 X 300`. However as I understand the dimensionality should be `77 x 77` (as my vocabulary size is 77).

```
i.e.,
      word1, word2, ......, word77
word1 0.2,     0.8,    ...,  0.9
word2 0.1,     0.2,   ....,  1.0
...  ....,    ....., .....,   ....
word77 0.9,  0.8,    ...,    0.1
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my code.

Moreover, I want to know what is the order of the vocabulary `(word1, word2, ..., word77)` used to calculate this similarity matrix? Can I obtain this `order` from `model.wv.index2word`?

Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace

```
index = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(model.wv.syn0))
```

to

```
index = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(model.wv.syn0.T))
```

Answer (score 3):

it's been long since this question has been posted, but maybe my answer will be of help.
The code below gives the same results as `index = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(model.wv.syn0.T))`, with the for loop, but is more concise.

```
import numpy as np    
similarity_matrix = np.dot(model.wv.syn0norm, model.wv.syn0norm.T)
```

It calculates the dot product between normalized word-vectors, i.e. distances between the pairs.